# AWS S3 Storage Class Settings in Serverless YAML

Tags: node.js, serverless

I am developing serverless API and I need to create a bucket with storage class "Intelligent Tiering".

Below are my settings in serverless.yml file:

```
BucketName:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  Properties:
    BucketName: prefix-${self:provider.stage}-${self:provider.region}

    BucketEncryption:
      ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
        - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
            SSEAlgorithm: AES256
    LifecycleConfiguration: 
      Rules:
      - Transition:
            StorageClass: INTELLIGENT_TIERING
            TransitionDate: 2019-06-14T00:00:00UTC+0530
            TransitionInDays: 2
```

I am getting the error with the Transition Date while deploying it on AWS Lambda which is mentioned below:

```
 Valud of property 2019-06-14T00:00:00UTC+0530 must be valid date time format
```

I have tried every possible time format to correct it but failed.
Please help to make correction while configuring bucket in serverless yaml file. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-lifecycleconfig-rule-transition.html

Indicates when objects are transitioned to the specified storage class. The date value must be in ISO 8601 format. The time is always midnight UTC.

Try this:
2019-06-14T00:00:00+05:30